# How to force domain to https on nodejs Angular Universal web app?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal app running on the Google Cloud platform on App Engine and I have my custom domain pointed to it.

How do I force my app to run on https. So how to do I force it from http to use https always?

Is it something I need to add in my server.js entrypoint file?

Comment: App Engine Standard or Flexible? Edit your question and include app.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect your app to https, you can add the following in your app.yaml file:

```
runtime: nodejs10

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

Comment: Note for future readers. This answer is only correct for App Engine Standard. This is not supported by App Engine Flexible.